# valign=t image but vertical center in rowcolor

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, rowcolor

I would like to have symmetrical padding at top and bottom of `valign=t`-ed images. I tried `array`'s `\extrarowheight`, which introduces some spacing between the images. However, when you add `rowcolors`, it doesn't look symmetric (it only adds space above, but not below).

Is there a way to

- Make images A and B not stick together
- Top-align them with text in first column
- Vertically center images and text in row color?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe} % blindtext, example image
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array} % required by tabularx; extrarowheight
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % valign
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{}
\setlength\extrarowheight{10pt}

\begin{tabularx}{15cm}{|X|X|}

    Foo &
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=t]{example-image-a} \\

    \blindtext &
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=t]{example-image-b} \\

    Bar &
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=t]{example-image-c} \\

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add below the image the same space as above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe} % blindtext, example image
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array} % required by tabularx; extrarowheight
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % valign
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{}
\setlength\extrarowheight{10pt}

\begin{tabularx}{15cm}{|X|X|}

    Foo &
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=t,trim=0pt -10pt 0pt 0pt]{example-image-a}\par\vspace{\extrarowheight} \\

    \blindtext &
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=t]{example-image-b} \\

    Bar &
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=t]{example-image-c} \\

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, negative trim! That's smart :)

Comment: Actually I wanted to remove this (it was from my first try but the trim gave a too small space). I'm not quite sure why one needs both values.

Answer (score 0):

To add some padding at the top and bottom of cells in a symmetricway, you can load `cellspace`, which defines a *minimal* vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S`  (or `C` if you load `siunitx`.

You also can play with the `padding= llx lly urx ury` key of `adjustbox`.

Finally, to have the text  in l.h.s. cells centred w.r.t. the image, change the definition of the `X` column type as  `m{some length}` instead of `p`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mwe} % blindtext, example image
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % valign
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{5pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|S{X}|X|}

    Foo &
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=t]{example-image-a} \\

    \blindtext &
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=t, padding = 0ex 2ex 0ex 2ex]{example-image-b} \\

    Bar &
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=t, padding = 0ex 0ex 0ex 2ex]{example-image-c} \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]